# Arduino/motor shield like controller for 24V DC motor

Tags: motor, dc, controller

I have a bunch of small 6V DC motors that I'm running off of an Arduino board and its motor shield. I am able to control the speed via PWM pins and the direction via DIR pins. I wrote a code that allows me to change these automatically every so often.

Now I'm looking for the same type of control but for a 24V DC motor. After some research I am under the impression that I need a motor driver. Would it still be possible to program an Arduino and use it as an input device to the motor driver? Or do I need a new programmable motor driver/controller? I plan to use a stock benchtop 0-30V power supply as the power source.

Or if you have any other ideas on how I could control this motor I'd appreciate any input. Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to find 24V motor drivers that can be controlled from Arduino.

Comment: What kind of motor (power ) ?   https://protype3d.fr/fr/664-driver-moteur-l298n.html  this can help you.